# How do I convert Postgres dates to ISO8601 in JSON responses with Vapor 3 running on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, vapor

I have a Vapor 3 API up on Heroku. Unfortunately, it's not handling dates correctly. Originally, I thought I could just treat dates like strings for simplicity in Vapor, like so:

```
struct MyModel {
  var time: String?
}
```

But whenever I fetch `MyModel`s from the db and return it, the `time` key doesn't appear at all (while other keys and values have no problems). I thought I might be able to just change `time`'s type to `Date`, but that resulted in the same thing, and I've already used `ContentConfig` to set the `JsonEncoder.dateEncodingStrategy` to `.iso8601` (again, no luck – perhaps because `dateEncodingStrategy` only supports millis on Linux, which is what Heroku uses?).

How do I convert Postgres dates to ISO8601 in json with Vapor 3 running on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! Just changed the properties to `Date`s, and manually converted request query parameters to `Date`s as well (for use in `filter` calls). So, a little more by hand than most things in Vapor 3, but not terrible.

Eg my model looks like this now:

```
struct MyModel {
  var time: Date?
}
```

And then when I try to filter by date I do something like this:

```
var builder = MyModel.query(on: req)
if let afterString: String = try? self.query.get(String.self, at: "after") {
    let afterDate: Date? = DateFormatter.iso8601Full.date(from: afterString)
    builder = builder.filter(\.time > afterDate)
}
```

where `after` is a url parameter, and `DateFormatter.iso8601Full` is my iso8601 date formatter. Then when I'm returning an array of `MyModel`s in a response, I map the array to an array of `MyModelResponseObject`s which look like this:

```
struct MyModelResponseObject {
  var time: String?
}
```

by doing something like this:

```
myModelsFuture.all().map(to: [MyModelResponseObject].self, { (myModels) -> [MyModelResponseObject] in 
    return myModels.map { it in
        return MyModelResponseObject(time: DateFormatter.iso8601Full.string(from: it.time ?? Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)))
    }
}
```

So basically I'm manually converting the dates into the format that I want when returning them in JSON.

Comment: How did you manually convert the request parameters to date ?